# iOS Simulator Springboard Memory Leak

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, ios-simulator, springboard

Did anyone experience huge memory leak with iOS Simulator lately?

Every time I'm trying to run my app in the Simulator, I'm getting SpringBoard memory leaks like that.

[image: Crazy SpringBoard memory consumption]

In an hour or so after that I'll have “Your system has run out of application memory” error (so I have to reboot my MacBook Pro with a button, because system is not working at this moment).

The problem is not in my app (I've tried two of them, and the second was fairly simple), and the problem is not with just one of the simulators (I've tried iPhone X and iPhone 7, both leaked, although 5s seemed ok).

(Unfortunately, I can't check what would happen if I tried to run an app on my device now)

XCode, Version 9.1 (9B55). iOS Simulator — Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-835.2.1).

I have 360GB available on my system disk and 16GB RAM. MacOS Sierra, 10.12.6.

Is there a way to work out these issues without reinstalling XCode?

Comment: Actually, no. It's just one of the first screenshots that I made. Right now I can easily make another one with XCode working just fine and the same SpringBoard memory usage.

XCode "not responding" is not the cause of this, it's the result.

Comment: You could be right. - But it's still not a Stack Overflow question. If you have a reproducible case, file a bug with Apple. (I suggest updating to the current Xcode 9.2 beta first, because they won't be interested if it doesn't show the same behavior.)

Comment: Why? It's not about coding per se, but it's about instruments we're using. I think it could be useful for other users with similar problems (even if we would be not able to find a good answer here, there is, at least, some temporary solution — not all the simulators are broken). This question seems ok to me and I believe it's not breaking the rules (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) — we can discuss software tools here.

Comment: I think you'd do better on the Apple developer forums, and even better submitting an actual bug report to Apple. I don't see what useful role you think Stack Overflow can play; what answer can be given? All you've asked is "Did anyone experience..." to which the only possible replies are "Yes" and "No." Okay: No. But I'm not using Xcode 9.1; I'm using the current beta, as I suggested you might do. And I don't do a lot of testing with outdated simulators.

Comment: Good point. Of course, my real question is not about finding other people with the same problem, I'm trying to find a solution here (and I don't suppose that someone have to play with simulators to answer my question as well). I don't think XCode beta is a good option because it has some restrictions (i.e. you won't be able to upload your apps to AppStore). But you're right, I'll update my question, and I'll try to download the latest beta too.

Comment: I would delete Xcode _and the old simulators_ and download everything afresh. I often have trouble caused by leftover simulators, so the first thing I do after updating Xcode is delete _all simulators_ and start over.